# How to send data by(chunks)? Python or NodeJS

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I would like to know if there is some way to send data part by part from Python or nodeJS. I mean, for example: I have a 20-second audio and I want to send 10 seconds in the first response and the other 10 seconds in a second response. How can I do it?

I found something about the pipe, but I’m really confused.

Extra: For example, [I'm listening to music on Spotify, and as you see in this image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBzhZ.png)

as you see in the previous image, every part of the marked data is about 10 seconds of the song.

I heard about pipe() in nodejs but I don't really get how to use it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I do not have any code yet, I'm just raising this situation. If you see the image above, you will get it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The client can request a range of bytes from the audio using the [Range header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range) and then the server can deliver that specific range.  This is how typical video or audio clients do streaming.  The client requests a byte range somewhat ahead of what it is already playing, trying to keep a small buffer of already downloaded audio or video, but not downloading too far ahead to avoid using too much memory.

If you look in more detail at the specific HTTP request from Spotify, you will probably see a Range header on the client requests.